# nektos/act: gh: command not found

Tags: git, github, testing, workflow, act

I use 'nektos/act' for testing my GitHub Actions locally. It works correctly when I use curl request inside yaml script. For example:

```
pull_info=$(curl -L -w "%{http_code}" \
           -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
           -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
           -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
           https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls/${{ github.event.pull_request.number }})
```

It gives me info about some pull request. But I should to exchange this curl request to CLI request, like this

```
pull_info=$(gh pr view ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }} --repo ${{ github.repository }} --json title,number,state)
```

I want to test it also, but act show me, that

```
/var/run/act/workflow/0: line 4: gh: command not found
```

I try to solve it. I found out that  should to install gh-act extension using this command

```
gh extension install nektos/gh-act
```

But it still also doesn't work. How can I fix it? Or may be it can be test another ways?

Comment: https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/1543 Found in https://github.com/nektos/act/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22gh+command+not+found%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just should to use the large docker image of act